# cx_Freeze: no base named Console

Tags: python, linux, build, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile a simple "Hello, world!" python script using cx_freeze (linux). I installed cx-freeze via the SourceForge tar file, because I had to apply [this](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304) patch.

However, when I run:

```
cx_Freeze-4.3.3$ ./cxfreeze hello.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cxfreeze", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/main.py", line 187, in main
    silent = options.silent)
  File "cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 108, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 488, in _VerifyConfiguration
    self._GetBaseFileName()
  File "cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 211, in _GetBaseFileName
    raise ConfigError("no base named %s", name)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem by changing

```
ext = ".exe" if sys.platform == "win32" else ""
```

to

```
ext = ".exe" if sys.platform == "win32" else ".py"
```

in file freezer.py